# Unresolved class MainActivity - AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have an Error in my AndroidManifest.xml I don't know why but it's just here...

This is AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="packagename">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So basically my Main Activity is pretty empty, and I don't know why this Appears here: C
My main activity:

```
package packagename;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

here is the image:
[image: here is the image]

Comment: is there any compilation error? or just red text?

Comment: It compiles normally, just the red text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a false error. Sometimes Android Studio goes mad. Just Restart the Android Studio and Open Project Again. It will solve the problem. If not restart your pc.

Answer (score 4):

File (Top menu) -> Invalidate caches / restart. It should resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line of code:

`<activity android:name="MainActivity"/>`

with this:

`<activity android:name="com.fayamedia.otakucounter.MainActivity"/>`

Comment: For me, the exact other way round worked. The generated code was `<activity android:name="com.fayamedia.otakucounter.MainActivity"/>` and changing it to `<activity android:name="MainActivity"/>` solved the issue...

Answer (score -1):

i also face this error i tried both invalid catches and rebuild project

.MainActivity error in android manifest
Occurred due to namespace error in build.gradle.app
Just change the name of your build.gradle.app  lowercase or same as project name
android

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).